# Использование библиотеки jQuery contextMenu

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Скачал с nuget jQuery contextMenu.
Всё необходимое подключил к проекту. Подключаю стили css.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

На прямую с сайта, всё работает как нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю из проекта:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Значки пропадают:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал даже с сайта скопировать содержимое и вставить в css файл в проекте. То же самое, иконок нет. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? И как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорей всего не загружается шрифт иконок. В консоле во вкладке Neywork какие-то ошибки есть?

Comment: @MishaSaidov да есть ошибки, как только вызываю меню сразу вылетает 3 ошибки, скинул скрин в вопрос.

Comment: @MishaSaidov я заметил что в проекте context-menu-icons хранятся в папке fonts, а css файл в контент, может как то нужно подключать ещё и иконки? Но с другой стороны, на сайте тот же самый код, я сам его перекопировал, а с сайта работает? Как так получается?

Comment: Вы скопировали папку fonts к себе? Если да, то меняли ли место ее расположения? По пути, по которому в консоле возникают ошибки, шрифты есть? Если нет, то попробуйте поместить шрифты по этому пути. Должно сработать

Comment: @MishaSaidov я установил всё из nuget. Код я скопировал с сайта только для того что бы проверить может установилась какая то старая весрия. А так всё что нужно и куда нужно вижла сама проставила.

Comment: @MishaSaidov и я немного не правильно написал, не в fonts, а в font. В fonts хранятся родные глиф айконы.